# Adding an integer variable to a list

Tags: python, list

```
if robotwalk <= 1 or robotwalk >= 8:
    robotfall +=1
    print"robotfalltrue"
    robotwalk=3.5
    robotlist =robotlist.append( robotsteps )
    robotsteps=0
    print robotlist
```

my question is is that how do fix this: i keep getting an error. robotlist =robotlist.append( robotsteps ). robot list has been defined as robotlist=[]

error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Answer (score 2):

`append()` modifies the list *in-place* and returns `None`. Therefore, all you need is

```
robotlist.append(robotsteps)
```

without the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

[The method `.append()` modifies the list in-place, and therefore returns nothing, hence `None`.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) Instead, just don't assign the output of `.append()` to any variable and the code will work like a charm:

```
if robotwalk <= 1 or robotwalk >= 8:
    robotfall +=1
    print"robotfalltrue"
    robotwalk=3.5
    robotlist.append( robotsteps )
    robotsteps=0
    print robotlist
```

Answer (score 0):

No re-assignment. Simply do this:

```
robotlist.append(robotsteps)
```

Or, alternately:

```
robotlist += [robotsteps]
```

But I think the first is more clear.

Comment: Thanks.  Caught that and put the brackets in. And I see you answered first. Cheers! :-)